# set range on HttpWebRequest headers in Metro App

Tags: c#, .net, http-headers, windows-store-apps

I am working on windows store app and I try to set a value for the range header on a HttpWebRequest but I can't figure out how to do this. The 3 solutions I tried don't work (exceptions or the method/property doesn't exist even if they are in the msdn documentation).

```
//Create the request.
        HttpWebRequest getRequest = WebRequest.Create(download.URI) as HttpWebRequest;

        // Set the request's method.
        getRequest.Method = "GET";

        //Set the Range'value on header
        /*(1)*/ getRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Range] = "bytes="+download.DownloadedBytes+"-";
        /*(2)*/ getRequest.Headers.Range = new RangeHeaderValue(download.DownloadedBytes,null);
        /*(3)*/ getRequest.Headers.AddRange(download.DownloadedBytes);
```

I know that HttpWebRequest has a semi-deprecated status but I don't want to use HttpClient class. I am not glad of how to retrieve error code when an http request failed.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

In your initial header

```
getRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Range] = "bytes="+download.DownloadedBytes+"-";
```

I'm not sure what your value is for download.DownloadedBytes, but I don't believe that string will satisfy the Range field header.  The string should be of form "bytes=500-999"

I've not made this work with HttpWebRequest, but I can offer a sample for HttpClient (sorry, I know you don't want to switch to this, but it might be for the best)

```
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("range", @"bytes=0-9000");
var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
```

Of course, should be noted that not all web servers will respect the range header.  Good luck!

Comment: I don't work on this project anymore, but if I remember, the exception was about some restricted access to the method. Unfortunately I can't test your solution now. However, for this project I just set my own header as I worked on the client and server side. Anyway, thanks for your answer and I will test your solution (some day)